# Foreach-loop - check if category is in sub-category of category

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have a foreach loop (wordpress template) that lists all the categories of the post except the "top news" category:

```
<?php
    $exclude = array("Top News");
    $catagorystring = '';
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
        if ( !in_array($category->cat_name, $exclude) ) {
            $catagorystring .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).get_option('category_base').'" class="category-link-einrichtungen">' . $category->name . '</a>, ';
        }
    }
    echo substr($catagorystring, 0, strrpos($catagorystring, ','));
?>
```

That works but in additional i want to hide child-categories of "top news", too.

There is a wordpress function that allows me to do something like this:

```
<?php if(post_is_in_descendant_category('3') ) { 
    echo 'is in category 3';
} ?>
```

But i have no idea how to get this into the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `parent` property of the category object and check it against any id of the categories in the `exclude` array:

```
$excludedCategories = array();
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
  $breakLoop = false;
  if (!in_array($category->cat_name, $exclude)) {
    foreach($exclude as $cat_name_to_exclude) {
      if($category->parent == get_cat_ID($cat_name_to_exclude)) {
        $breakLoop = true;
      }
    }
    if($breakLoop) {
      array_push($excludedCategories, $category);
      continue;
    }
    $categorystring .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).get_option('category_base').'" class="category-link-einrichtungen">' . $category->name . '</a>, ';
  }
}
```

Comment: Strange thing is that this shows me only the children of "Top News", but these i want to hide and show only the rest.

Comment: @HenningFischer My bad the code logic was false (seems I need some sleep after all :) ), see updated answer.

Comment: Hi, when I want to display the rest of the categories I use "$exclude = array(!"Top News");" and repeat the rest of the code, is this a good practice? Or is there a way to just split the loop?

Comment: What do you mean, you want to loop a second time on the template to display all the categories? Because this loop should display all the categories except the excluded one + his childs.

Comment: Yes and i want to show in a second loop the only the ones that are exluded in the first loop. I am doing this with the same loop but with a "!" ($exclude = array(!"Top News");), but i ask myself if this is the "right" way to do this. Because I am a PHP novice i just would like to learn ;) .

Comment: See my updated answer, I added an array named `$excludedCategories` that you can use after the loop, it content all the categories that have been excluded.

Comment: Thanks for your help to bring light into the dark ;) .